# Print change text in spool file

Tags: c#, windows, spooler

I want to make a Windows service in c# that can change some content which is going to print.

For that i have tried to modify the .SPL file which is generated in spool folder in system32.

I have download one sample from
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10586/EMF-Printer-Spool-File-Viewer

which convert SPL file to Image but I need text which is not possible.

How to change content before making .SPL file or any suggestion.

### Example

This is original text

---

In print

This is duplicate text

---

### edited as no response get

Is there any way to read directly from printer port in c# application?

Please note that i am using shared usb printer...

serial port programming is useless..

so anyone know read from usb port..

Comment: You would have to intercept the data before it got to the printer, once its in the queue  printers dont "hold" the job while you edit them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but i want to make general window service. If someone print from MSOffice, PDF etc than that window service will get the content and save in the database. Do u know how to do so

Comment: I cant see a way for you to do this the way you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a virtual printer driver to intercept the print job and modify it before sending the final print to the actual printer.

https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/print/virtual-printer

Comment: That approach means the user can only print to your printer. OP is asking how to modify print jobs on any printer. Totally different questions.